# Can't use Mapstruct ADDER_PREFERRED to not clear target list with @MappingTarget

Tags: mapping, mapstruct

my goal is to map source object to an existing target object, including some of list-properties (in source and target).
According to the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances),

> For CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED or CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE the target will not be cleared and the values will be populated immediately.

and that's what I want.

So I'm making test class:

```
@Data
public class MainClass {

class ClassA {
    List<ClassC> list;

}

class ClassB {
    List<ClassD> list;
    
}

class ClassC {

}

class ClassD {

}
```

}

and following mapper with collectionMappingStrategy and @MappingTarget:

```
@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED)
public interface TestMapper {

TestMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( TestMapper.class );

void map(List<MainClass.ClassA> sourse, @MappingTarget List<MainClass.ClassB> target);

MainClass.ClassB map(MainClass.ClassA sourse);
```

}

but in the mapper implementation I see **clearing of target's list**, which I do not need:

```
public class TestMapperImpl implements TestMapper {

@Override
public void map(List<ClassA> sourse, List<ClassB> target) {
    if ( sourse == null ) {
        return;
    }

    target.clear();
    for ( ClassA classA : sourse ) {
        target.add( map( classA ) );
    }
}

@Override
public ClassB map(ClassA sourse) {
    if ( sourse == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    ClassB classB = new ClassB();

    return classB;
}
```

}

Am I reading or doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED` is meant for adders on objects. Such as a `Car` having a method `addWheel(Wheel wheel)`, and not meant for mapping collections.

The `CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE` is meant for not doing a `clear` or `addAll` when mapping collection properties. i.e.

> Instead the target accessor (e.g. set) will be used on the target bean to set the collection.

Both of these have no influence when mapping collections like in your example.

What I would suggest here is to use your own custom mapping

e.g.

```
@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED)
public interface TestMapper {

    TestMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( TestMapper.class );

    default void map(List<MainClass.ClassA> source, @MappingTarget List<MainClass.ClassB> target) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return;
        }

        for ( ClassA classA : source ) {
            target.add( map( classA ) );
        }
    }

    MainClass.ClassB map(MainClass.ClassA sourse);
```